# How do I sort a ruby hash by keys according to the order of those keys in an array?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash of some random order and the keys of that hash are are in an array.

```
my_array = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE']
my_hash = { 'THREE' => "this is the third", 
            'ONE' => "this is the first",
            'TWO' => 'second' }
```

How to get this ordered in a way where

```
new_hash = { 'ONE' => "this is the first",
             'TWO' => 'second',
             'THREE' => "this is the third" }
```

Comment: Why order the hash? That doesn't do much good since they're random access. Simply get the keys in the order of `my_array`.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users. We'd like to see your effort, either where you searched for solutions and why those didn't help, or in the minimum code showing what you wrote to solve the problem and an explanation why it doesn't work correctly. Without that looks like you're asking us to solve the problem for you. And, just so you know, this question has been asked multiple times on SO, so the answer is out there.

Comment: @theTinMan is there a case for rearranging a hash for readability?

Comment: Why would you need to make a hash readable? You might want to make `inspect` more readable, or you might want to iterate over the hash and make _that_ output more readable, but in either case it doesn't involve changing the hash or its order, only the order that data is retrieved from the hash and the format of that output.

Comment: To be clearer, how to iterate the hash according to the order of its keys from an array?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
my_array = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE']
my_hash = { 'THREE' => "this is the third", 
            'ONE' => "this is the first",
            'TWO' => 'second' }

my_array.zip(my_array.map {|s| my_hash[s]}).to_h
#=> {"ONE"=>"this is the first", "TWO"=>"second", "THREE"=>"this is the third"}
```

Comment: Expecting a hash to have a particular order can be problematic, so it's best avoided.

Comment: Hashes maintain their insertion order, which is kinda nice, but it's hardly essential, nor should it be counted on as @tadman says. Get in the habit of ordering the keys, then extracting the values in that order; `values_at` is our friend and makes it very easy. Sorting or ordering the keys in a hash really only wastes CPU time since the same thing can be accomplished when retrieving the values.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean. Having to rebuild the hash just to get some arbitrary ordering is expensive, such as you'd have to do when inserting a key between two other keys. Treating them like arrays, which are intrinsically ordered, is usually a mistake. They're only ordered for consistency's sake: Two hashes produced the same way are going to be identical. Historically this wasn't the case, they'd often be randomized and unpredictable.